# Sending UDP packets to offline host in same subnet long delay

Tags: c#, networking, udp, udpclient

I run simple UDP client program on Windows 7 host. The network configuration is `192.168.1.50` host IP, `255.255.255.0` subnet mask, `192.168.1.1` default gateway.

```
var data = new byte[1200];    
var sender = new UdpClient();
// takes ~2900 ms to non-existing host in same subnet
sender.Send(data, data.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.5"), 999));
// takes ~0 ms to non-existing host outside subnet
sender.Send(data, data.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.8.8"), 999));
```

Sending UDP packet to non-existing host (eg `192.168.1.5`) in same subnet takes about 3 seconds. But when I change destination address to non-existing address outside my subnet (eg `192.168.8.8`), packet is transmitted almost instantly.

If I set `data` size less or equal to 1024 bytes, the packet is transmitted almost instantly in both cases.

Is that an inherent property of network stack implementation or it can be tuned some way?

Comment: I think what is making this delay is an ARP broadcast looking for the non-existing host MAC in the same subnet. This is not happening in the non-existing host in other sub-net as in this case, the gateway knows without broadcasting nothing that it's unable to reach an unexistant network.

Comment: On the Windows 10 host delay is about zero in both cases. Looks like it depends on `FastSendDatagramThreshold‌` value.

Comment: The non existing IP is not inside the mask so it is going to an non existing Ethernet card on the PC and gets returned immediately.

Comment: "when I change destination address to non-existing address outside my subnet (eg 192.168.8.8), packet **is transmitted almost instantly** "  - I think it is in fact _not transmitted_ at all.